# Tracking child workflow internal activities

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation, workflow-activity

I'm facing a problem concerning **WF4** and **CustomTrackingRecord** for Child Workflow loaded dynamically from .xaml by **WorkflowInvoker**. 
The execution works really well and I'm able to track InArguments and OutArguments, but not internal activities as I already do for level 0 Workflows (parents). Here the code for InArgs and OutArgs tracking.

```
var userRecord = new CustomTrackingRecord("InArguments");
        foreach (var kvp in inArgs) {
            userRecord.Data.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value == null ? "" : kvp.Value.ToString());
        }
        context.Track(userRecord);
```

...

```
 WorkflowInvoker invoker = new WorkflowInvoker(dynamicActivity);
            outArgs = invoker.Invoke(inArgs);


            foreach (string argumentKey in outArgs.Keys) {
                this.ChildArguments[argumentKey].Set(context, outArgs[argumentKey]);
            }

            userRecord = new CustomTrackingRecord("OutArguments");
            foreach (var kvp in outArgs) {
                userRecord.Data.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value == null ? "" : kvp.Value.ToString());
            }
            context.Track(userRecord);
```

I'm pretty sure that invoker.Invoke(inArgs) should start the standard tracking system, in few words the perfectly working one used to know what happens into Activity, but it seems to ignore what happens into DynamicActivity.

Any Idea? Context issue? Type issue?

Thanks, Francesco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WorkflowInvoker is a different execution with its own extensions. So to add those events to the same TrackingParticipant you need to add that to the invoker.Extensions collection.

Something like:

```
var invoker = new WorkflowInvoker(dynamicActivity);
var tracker = context.GetExtension<TrackingParticipant>();
invoker.Extensions.Add(tracker);
outArgs = invoker.Invoke(inArgs);
```

Comment: Thank you Maurice, it seems to go into my SqlTrackingParticipant.Track method now, but logs are missing. I'm going to investigate updating my post whenever I'll find a solution.

Comment: Not quite sure I understand _logs are missing_. Is the SqlTrackingParticipant.Track not called for each event or are they missing in the database?

Comment: I've solved! My SELECT query works retrieving logs by workflows ID and Child WF has obviously a different ID from its Parent. So track method is called for every activity and logs are written and read! Thank you again!